# how to see how much we have gained badge wise

Tags: discussion, badges

I would like to know where we can see the percentage towards any badge we have accumilatede towards? so where you click on badges it doesnt state 10 out of 100 so i know i have 90 left to get that badge or am i mistaken?

also i have looked at one of the post where it shows a link to a site where it contains scripts to use (entering username) but they dont work?? the ones that do work are old and irrelavent to my needs question :)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of discussion on meta about this.

[Why is badge progress only shown in review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163879/why-is-badge-progress-only-shown-in-review)

[How can I see my progress for different badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137959/how-can-i-see-my-progress-for-different-badges)

the general answers seems to indicate that most of the user are fine with the current situation and they don't feel need for other stats.

You best bet would be an app or a grease script. This post

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137960/171199

reference an app, but I never used it so I don't know if it is accurate (or if it will steal your soul and sell it to Cthulhu in exchange for some SharePoint insider documentation).

Comment: thanks, the last url was what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Some badges are available for viewing "badge progress" and they are located in the review (white arrow) section. Click `review > recent reviews` and hover the number at the top of the content section (marked in red):

[image]

On the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/queries) you can search for [badge progress](http://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/queries?q=badge%20progress) or write your own query, but you have to use your UserID not your UserName. Your UserID is located in the URL of your profile (by clicking your name):

```
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/6382/benny-skogberg
```

Mine is 6382, as you can see from the above URL.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i already know bout that, it only shows three types that i see regularly! I talking about others that you cant see that are within the badges list, i dunno if its even possible tbh? it would be nice tho to be added